# Height of table cell with hidden overflow child items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to get the real height of the content of a table cell with nested child items that may contain overflow:hidden style, like so:

```
<tr>
    <td id="targetid">
        <div id="innertargetdiv">
            <div id="targetiddiv" style="overflow:hidden; max-height:50px;">
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
```

JS code:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("targetid").scrollHeight);
console.log(document.getElementById("innertargetdiv").scrollHeight);
console.log(document.getElementById("targetiddiv").scrollHeight);
```

Output:
51
50
100

How can I get the full height from "#targetid" level?
I don't want the content to fill the entire cell, I just want to know the entire height. AngularJS/JQuery are also options.

Possible recursive sollution for the problem:

```
var totalHeight: (any) => number = (e) => {
                var eHeight = 0;

                if (e.hasChildNodes()) {
                    eHeight = $.map(e.children, (child) => totalHeight(child))
                        .reduce((sum: number, value: number) => sum + value, 0);
                }

                //The height of the child elements might be smaller than the element with padding
                return Math.max.apply(Math, [eHeight, e.scrollHeight]);
            };
```

Comment: You have `max-height: 50px` so you're going to get that height, assuming there's no space taken up outside of that.

Comment: yep, another way of getting that 100 height from #targetid level? it could also imply cloning the dom element, manipulating its css .. some rows of the table will surely have overflowing content ..

Comment: I was also thinking about a possible recursive solution but the approach posted above has problems with floating elements because if 2 siblings are flowting and above cod sums their height it won't show the true height of the parent... I should only take vertically staked siblings, don't know how to do that one

Comment: I wonder if AngularJS might be another approach, I could get the DOM element in the linking phase and bind the data in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, here's an example with cloning the element.

```js
const targetElm = document.getElementById('targetid')
const clonedElm = document.createElement('div')

clonedElm.setAttribute('id', 'clonedTarget')
clonedElm.style.visibility = 'hidden'
clonedElm.innerHTML = targetElm.innerHTML.replace(/target/g, 'clone')    

const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
body.append(clonedElm)
document.getElementById('cloneiddiv').style = ''

const height = document.getElementById('innerclonediv').scrollHeight
document.getElementById('clonedTarget').remove()

console.log(height)
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
    <td id="targetid">
        <div id="innertargetdiv">
            <div id="targetiddiv" style="overflow:hidden; max-height:50px;">
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
                Thiscell<br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Is cloning the element, that much of a performance issue? or is it acceptable?

Comment: What about a more generic approach for this? like: innertargetdiv has unknown number of child nodes, each with possibly nested childs that have hidden overflow content, see where I'm getting with this?